# How to add image attribute in 2.0

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-images, magento-2.0

I'm trying to add an image attribute to peer on the product page above the product name.  Any idea what file I can look into to get this to show up? I've already created the attribute it shows up in the backend but I cannot make it show up on the product page .

Answer (score 3):

If you will create any attribute of "Media Image Type" then no setting related to "Store Front Properties" will come in admin. That's why it's not coming in Product Page. There is no field in admin through which you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your new attribute must be added to the attribute group that your product uses.  Also, the attribute's Storefront Properties->Used in Product Listing must be set to Yes.